# How to block and allow other apps from Accesing the internet in android programatically?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-networking, android-connectivitymanager

My idea is to to design a android apps that allow or block internet traffic of selected apps acording to my wish in non-rooted phone.

I know it is possible, but anyone please help me in achieving this.

There are some apps like mobiwol etc., which helps in allowing or blocking internet to apps.

I searched internet but get nothing working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it will be possible without giving admin permission to the app.

Comment: some apps available in playstore like netblocker do this witout admin permission, i think they se connectivityManager to achieve this but didn't know how to implement this